# Convert Url with php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

How can I convert a string like this:

```
[www.example.com?type=PC&brand=Dell&id=2]
```

to

```
[www.example.com/PC/Dell/2.html]
```

thz for your help!

Comment: **HTACCESS URL REWRITE** is the answer

Comment: @Mr.Alien: He never said anything about "rewriting", he was talking about "replacing".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't expect from you that you didn't got what he really wanted, he must not be knowing the real word

Comment: @Mr.Alien: He's specifically asking about **converting strings**, whether he's using it as a rewrite, or just to render a pretty URL, that's not up to you to assume.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha lets see what he really wants

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I think we just did.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha hahaha :) but that was a nice piece of code from you and btw I believe you downvoted Zoltan's answer, take that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html www.example.com?type=$1&brand=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: See my comment on the question. OP never said anything about rewriting. He wants replacing.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it turned out the OP really wanted the rewrite not the string conversion ;-)

Comment: Indeed it has. Which means the OP could do some clarification in his question.

Answer (score 3):

***If you want to map the first link into the second, to make the URLs on your site prettier, go with `.htaccess` and `Mod_rewrite`!***

This is the correct solution:

```
$str = "[www.example.com?type=PC&brand=Dell&id=2]";

$str = trim($str,"[]"); //Remove square brackets, we'll add them back later
$url = parse_url($str); //Parse the URL into an array

$query = $url["query"]; //Part after the ?

$parts = explode("&", $query); //Have each GET variable into an array element
$parts = array_map(function($e) {
    return preg_replace("/[^=]+=/", "", $e);
}, $parts); //Remove the part before the =.

$parts = implode("/", $parts); //Implode it back into a string.
$result = $url["path"] . "/" . $parts . ".html"; //Putting it back together
$result = "[$result]"; //I promised I'll put it back!

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I will upvote this one as this is the answer according to the question though OP thought otherwise and accepted different.